# SharePoint Site backup fails with error "message":"The request has been throttled","retryAfterSeconds":33,"@error.X-ClientErrorCode":"quota"}}

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup, resource-throttling

We are backing up SharePoint Online site through a third party tool called Datto SaaS Backup.

It has been now failing for over a month for only one specific site with below error:

> "message":"The request has been throttled","retryAfterSeconds":33,"@error.X-ClientErrorCode":"quota"}}

All retry attempts are continually failing.  Raised support ticket with both parties but no one is able to assist on fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to persevere with your third party as this a SaaS product. If they are unable to provide the service advertised, then you'll need to go down the customer service route.

Throttling in SharePoint Online occurs when you make a large volume of calls and go over the [throttling thresholds](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online). It is therefore unsurprising that throttling is a problem for these sorts of backups services, though I am unaware of any potential workarounds or methods these backup services employ to avoid throttling.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Callum Crowley. I've tried the Customer service which has not been of any help at all.  They say its a throtlling issue that's all.  Happening since Dec 2nd till now.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online

When usage limits are exceeded, SharePoint Online throttles any further requests from that client for a short period. For requests that an application makes, including Microsoft Graph, CSOM or REST calls, SharePoint Online returns HTTP status code 429 (“Too many requests”) or 503 (“Server Too Busy”) and the requests will fail. In both cases, a Retry-After header is included in the response indicating how long the calling application should wait before retrying or making a new request.

If the offending application continues to exceed usage limits, SharePoint Online may completely block the application or specific request patterns from the application. In this case, the application will keep getting HTTP status code 503, and Microsoft will notify the tenant of the block in the Office 365 Message Center.

Decrease the number of requests: To stop throttling, you must temporarily decrease the number of requests you issue to SharePoint.
Honor the Retry-After header: Throttled requests count towards usage limits, so failure to honor Retry-After may result in more throttling.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your inputs. I think they are already honoring Retry-After but no luck.  Nothing in the O365 Admin Center indicating any blocks.  BTW, this issue is only existent to a specific Sharepoint site.  All the other Sharepoint Sites are being backed up successfully.